# Shortcut to create property associated to a field?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have to make many combination of field and property. I cannot use the implicit property version "{ get; set; }" since the fields need some attributes.

So, in Visual Studio Express 2013, is there a way to have a shortcut to create a property associated with a field I just ended up writing?

Let's say I write;

```
private MyType myData;
```

and I press CTRL+P (whatever the shortcut), and it adds

```
public MyType MyData
{
    get { return myData; }
    set { myData = value; }
}
```

just after.

Is it possible?

EDIT:
***The Express version however does only have two refactoring functionalities: rename and extract method, the other functionalities like encapsulate are not present.***

I guess I'm stuck.

Comment: You can type "prop" and tab then

Comment: I know about "prop", but it just spit the generic `public int MyProperty { get; set; }`. Or "propfull". It's not an int, it's not named MyProperty. I already have a field written with the proper names and type. It's almost as fast to write it manually.

Comment: rigth-click in your field then Refactor-->EncapsulateField and your done.

Comment: I don't know why @Daniel removed his answer, but the built-in `propfull` snippet is what you're after.

Comment: @CodeCaster Because it is not what I'm after. `prop` and `propfull` just spit an `int MyProperty`. My field is not named `myfield` and it's not an int.

Comment: If you type `propfull` followed by `Tab`, you can enter the property type. If you press `Tab` again, you can edit the name.

Answer (score 2):

By what you are asking 3 simple clicks will do it like this:

rigth-click in your field then `Refactor`-->`EncapsulateField`

And your done.

Comment: I don't have "EncapsulateField" in Refactor. My guess is, this is not part of VS Express?

Comment: strange it should be there,try highligthing the field and press this combination   Ctrl + R,E  and tell me if the encapsulatefield dialog shows.

Comment: "CTRL+R, E" is not a command. "CTRL+R, CTRL+E" is not a command. :(

Comment: did you highlighted the field first?

Comment: Yes, I did highlight the field. "The express version however does only have two refactoring functionalities: rename and extract method, the other functionalities like encapsulate are not present." Guess I'm stuck.

Comment: i belive you but it should be there,well...why don you try coderush - https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/

Comment: Visual Studio Express doesn't support plugin. :/

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx

this might also be useful (Create your own snippets) :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165394.aspx

here you have all the code snippets you need including "prop", which is the one you need now!

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't want 'prop'. It just create the generic `public int MyProperty { get; set; }`

Comment: It looks like LightStriker need to manage his own custom snippets

Comment: Check out the second link...i just edited the answer

Comment: From what I see in there, I would need an "Refactoring" snippet type, and they don't seem to work on VS Express. At least, from what I see.

Answer (score 1):

Type prop
then press tab
then enter the property name
then press ctrl+.
then click on convert to full property

Answer (score 0):

You should use code snippet and assign hotkey for it.

More information about managing code snippets here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx